# Optional replacement in a Regular Expression

Tags: regex, vba

I am creating a regular expression, in VBA that uses the JS flavor of RegEx. Here is the issue I have ran into:

Current RegEx:

```
(^6)(?:a|ab)?
```

I have a 6 followed by either nothing, an 'a' or 'ab'.

In the case of a 6 followed by nothing I want to return just the 6 using $1
In the case of a 6 followed by an 'a' or 'ab' I want to return 6B

So I need that 'B' to be optional, contingent on there being an 'a' or 'ab'.

Something to the effect of : $1B?

That of course does not work. I only want the B if the 'a' or 'ab' is present, otherwise just the $1.

Is this possible to do in a single regex pattern? I could just have 2 separate patterns, one looking for only a 6 and the other for 6'a'or'ab'... but my actual regex patterns are much more complicated and I might need several patterns to cover some of them...

Thanks for looking.

Comment: So, you are using this in Excel/Word? Could you show the code you have? And first of all, your regex should look like `(^6)(?:ab|a)?`, or `(^6)(?:ab?)?`. And also note there is no optional or conditional replacement with a literal. You need to access `Submatches` to decide what to do with the string.

Comment: This sounds extremely artificial, what are you *really* trying to do? You're using this regex to extract information from strings, so what information are you trying to detect that requires either "6" or "6B" depending on context? (They way you've stated the problem now suggest there being no point in using a RegEx. Just has two if statements based on `string.char(0)` and `string.char(1)`)

Comment: If you want `6` followed by nothing to be replaced by `6`, then nevermind that because that's no change. Just find `/6ab?/` and replace it with `6B`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your question is clearly defined--for example, I don't know why you need a replace--but from what I can infer, something like the following may work for you:

```
target = "6ab"
result = ""

With New RegExp
    .Pattern = "^(6)(?:a(b?))?"

    Set matches = .Execute(target)

    If Not matches Is Nothing Then
        Set mat = matches(0)

        result = mat.SubMatches(0)

        If mat.SubMatches.Count > 1 Then
            result = result & UCase(mat.SubMatches(1))
        End If
    End If

    Debug.Print result
End With
```

You basically inspect the capture groups to determine whether or not there was a hit on the `b` capture. Whereas you used `a|ab`, I think and optional b (`b?`) is more to the point. It's probably stylistic more than anything.

Comment: When using `a|ab`, you will never get `ab`, the difference is not just "stylistic", but it does not matter in this case, since this is just an example.

Comment: @stribizhev Ah, very true. Wasn't thinking about that at the time :)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, there is no way to tell a regex engine to choose between literal alternatives in the replacement string. Thus, all you can do is to access `Submatches` to check for values that you get there, and return appropriate values.

Note that a regex you have should have 2 *capturing* groups, or at least a capturing group where you do not know the exact text (the `(ab?)`).

Here is my idea in code:

```
Function RxCondReplace(ByVal str As String) As String
RxCondReplace = ""
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegExp.Pattern = "^6(ab?)?"          
Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(str)
Set objMatch = objMatches.Item(0)           ' Only 1 match as .Global=False
 If objMatch.SubMatches.Item(0) = "a" Or _ ' check if 1st group equals "a"
   objMatch.SubMatches.Item(0) = "ab" Then ' check if 1st group equals "ab"
   RxCondReplace = "6B"
 ElseIf objMatch.SubMatches.Item(1) = "" Then ' check if 2nd group is empty
   RxCondReplace = "6"
 End If
End Function

' Calling the function above
Sub CallConditionalReplace()
Debug.Print RxCondReplace("6")   ' => 6
Debug.Print RxCondReplace("6a")  ' => 6B
Debug.Print RxCondReplace("6ab") ' => 6B
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe length of the match [0]  on `^6(ab?)?  > 1 replace with 6B else 6 ?